# what is the time complexity of T(n)= 3T(n/2) + n^2?

Tags: recursion, time-complexity

I tried using recursive tree method.
and got a geometric series.
That follows :

kn^2(1+ (3/2) +(3/2)^2 +...+(3/2)^b)

The sum = a(r^m -1)/r-1.

b = log n.

Then what to do I got confused.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a mathematics question, not a computer programming question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it would be better suited to cs.stackexchange.com

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have you heard of the [Master's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms))? Your example is a relatively simple subcase (no logarithms). The result is:

```
T = Theta(n^2)
```

Comment: yep I have heard of it. But I am just starting to learn time analysis of recursion. So, I am  going from substitution/ iterative method to master theorem. Therefore, now I am just solving this above mentioned question by recursive tree method. I APPRECIATE YOUR HELP! .  THANK YOU FOR YOUR ANSWER. NOW, AT LEAST I CAN VERIFY MY ANSWER

Comment: @SwayamSwastik Well, good luck then.